What airplane is this?



I came across these images (probably taken around 2014-2015, by Arthur le Fol) of a pop group sitting on the engines of an airplane, but I don't recognize the plane. (Images are links to the sites they came from). What airplane is this? Where could it have been taken?

Oops; didn't do a good job searching this time. Turns out the images are excerped from a music video.
